# With Google Domain Shared Contacts API how to add a group member

Tags: javascript, google-contacts-api

I am using the Google Shared Domain Contacts API ([reference](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts/overview)) to fetch and update external contacts, the documentation is pretty sparse but does mention gContact:groupMembershipInfo however I am not sure how to use it to add/remove/view groups for external contacts